# How to load test a web page using Windows authentication

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, load-testing

I'm in the process of developing some load tests for an internal web application.

The problem appears to be related to our use of Windows authentication. I can access the web application if I launch the browser and nevigate to our app. I can't, however, access the application via webrequest in my load test. It throws a 401 exception, Unauthorized.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

How do I use my Windows credentials in my load test? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this works...

```
 request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Select The Test Main node, and click the red marked button to set credentials]

Select The Test Main node, and click the red marked button to set credentials

Answer (score 0):

If your load testing tool doesn't have a way to specify the credentials to run under, you will have to use Windows Impersonation (just to perform your tests).

You could potentially do this in code (see here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx), but if you don't need to get fancy, it will be easier to update your web.config with the credentials to run under:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

This *should* work for any pages under the web site for which the web.config is configured.