# How to load test an asp.net mvc app that needs authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, load-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to load test an asp.net 5 / mvc 6 app.  The app requires authentication to login - specifically I am using Office365/AzureAD to authenticate users.

Using VS2015, I setup a Web Performance and Load Test Project.  I added and  recorded a web test via the IE Web Test Recorder add-in.  However, it doesn't seem like the recorder records authorization information, thus everything fails during replay/load test.

I don't see any obvious way to plug in authentication information.  Am I missing something obvious?

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190758/how-to-load-test-a-web-page-using-windows-authentication), but it deals with Windows authentication.  As this authentication for AzureAD, the tricks in that question do not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load test a web page using Windows authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190758/how-to-load-test-a-web-page-using-windows-authentication) and see the asnwer by Bishoy Hanna

Comment: @AdrianHHH Unfortunately I've tried it and it doesn't work for AzureAD authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the specific mechanism for your authentication needs. One possibility is to record the entire transaction (including the authentication) with a program such as Fiddler and work out the authentication process then duplicate that in Visual Studio.

On one of my projects the mechanism required was simply to add a new header field to each request, its value being the username and password (plus a few other fixed characters) all encoded in base-64.